# SwiftUI and UIKit Interoperability with displaying multiple views

Tags: swiftui, uikit, mapkit, uiviewrepresentable, observedobject

Overview: I'm using SwiftUI, but wanted to use UIKit-MapKit. I used UIViewRepresentable to be able to wrap the UIKit feature.

Problem: I'm learning about swiftui-uikit-interoperability and I'm getting stuck on being able to display multiple SwiftUI views.

Code Snippet:

ContentView

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: MapView.PinViewModel
    
    init() {
        self.viewModel = MapView.PinViewModel()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MapView()

            .sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.showPinForm) {
                PinForm()
            }
            
            .navigationTitle("SwiftUI UIKit Interop").scaledToFill()
        }
    }
}
```

MapView

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {

    class PinViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var showPinForm: Bool
        
        init() {
            self.showPinForm = false
        }

        func updateShowPinVar() {
            self.showPinForm = true
        }
    }

    func showPinForm() {
        pinViewModel.updateShowPinVar()
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> MapViewCoordinator {
        let coordinator = MapViewCoordinator()
        coordinator.delegate = self
        return coordinator
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.7209, longitude: -74.0007)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.03, longitudeDelta: 0.03)
        let mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
        mapView.setRegion(mapRegion, animated: true)
        return mapView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

In this I have a @Published var showPinForm that gets toggled in MapView. ContentView is supposed to watch this variable and when it is true it will cause the sheet to pull up. However, I believe when I enter MapView() from ContentView() then I no longer recognize ContentView.

Using the UIViewRepresentable, what is the best way to display another swiftui view? Does not have to use .sheet (Although, it would be nice)

- I have tried to simplify the code to show the main problem, so I left out a lot of additional info and took out basic patterns that I used (MVVM)
  Please let me know if you need any clarifications

Comment: you cannot implement `ObservableObject` for a View, it's for ViewModel. Add a callback or binding for your MapView

Comment: @QuangHà I cut out a important chunk of code, but it's updated now. I did't actually have observableobject in the view. I have it in a class.

Comment: How do you create `pinViewModel` in `MapView` and where do you call `showPinForm`? Actually you need to use same instance of view model in both `ContentView` and `MapView` to have communication between them.

Comment: We don't use MVVM in SwiftUI we use View structs for the view data and property wrappers like @ State and @ Binding to make our structs behave like objects. Best to learn this first before tackling interoperability.

Comment: @Asperi I was not using the same instance of viewModel in ContentView and MapView. I made these changes and this fixed it. Simple overlook, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

try to follow this pattern, you can toggle the flag both inside and outside your MapView

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var switcher: Bool // -> use binding
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView { MKMapView() }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) { }
}
struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = MainViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        MapView(switcher: $viewModel.flag)
            .sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.flag) {
                Text("Pin pin")
            }
    }
}
class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var flag: Bool = false
}
```

Comment: When I implement it like this, I get an error on line                                        
 MapView(ditto: ditto, switcher: $viewModel.flag)                                                                     The error says "Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Bool>' to expected argument type 'Bool'" since flag is a bool and switcher is a binding<bool>